# query distinct returns 5 fields but if 1 field not distinct but matches a certain number i want that in the result set

Tags: ms-access, distinct

table1

```
att_id name tel
a1       Joe  123456
a2       Tom  456789
a3       mary  444444
a4       sue   333333
```

table 2

```
group_id desc  att_id
5        red     a1
10       blue    a1
12       orange  a1
6        green   a2
5        red     a2
10       blue    a3
6        green   a3
5        red     a4
10       blue    a4
6        green   a4
```

i want 1 row per att_id, where group id <> 12. but here's the problem. if that attendee does have  a group record that is 5 (red) then I want to see that.

ie

att_id a1 is not on list because it has an item in group 12, which is correct

Results:

```
a2  tom  456789  red
a3  mary 444444
a4  sue  333333  red
```

my query goes something like this:

SELECT DISTINCT   Name, Phone
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.Att_ID = table2.Att_ID
WHERE (table1.Att_ID Not In (select Att_ID from table2 where table2.Group_ID = 12))

this works to exclude the records from table 1 that have a group id 12 in table 2.I don't know how look at the records that get returned to determine if any of them have a 'red' group, yet still only have 1 record returned for that att_id, just with a col to indicate they had a red group record in table 1

sorry not sure how to articulate this well.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `DLookup()` for the "red" column seems to work:

```
SELECT 
    att_id, 
    [name], 
    tel, 
    DLookup("[desc]", "table2", "att_id=""" & att_id & """ AND [desc]=""red""") AS red
FROM table1
WHERE att_id NOT IN (SELECT att_id FROM table2 WHERE group_id=12)
```